# Restore a string that has randomly inserted characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to clean this string `How52363262362366are9you?`, or any similar string that the user inputs, using wherever character he wants.

This was my first approach :

```js
function buildstring(str){
  var reg =/[0-9]/g;
  let newStr = str.replace(reg, '');
  return newStr;
}

console.log(buildstring('How52363262362366are9you?'));
```

This way I'm only deleting the digits. I can make the regex even better by adding some non alphanumeric characters, but let's keep it simple.

This function returns `Howareyou?`. Now I want to separate the words with a space to reconstruct the sentence.

My first idea was using `split('')`, but of course didn't work...

How to solve this? Is there any way to make that a word starts at point a and ends in point c?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. First, you're talking about best practice to "refactor" a string without any context, then you're replacing some random numbers and then you're talking about separating words by space. Can you, please, formulate a single question with actual input and expected output?

Comment: I reformulated the question, removing "best practice", but yes, this needs clarification.

Comment: What about "real" numbers in the sentence? If you use `.replace(/\d+/g, ' ')`, you will remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your regex a bit so that it matches grouped numerical characters, and replace each group with a space.

```
function buildstring(str){
  var reg =/[0-9]+/g;
  let newStr = str.replace(reg, ' ')

  return newStr
}


buildstring('How52363262362366are9you?')
```

Answer (score 0):

there are several approaches.
You could consider it a case for Functional Programming (since there's a flow of transformations).
Something like this:

```js
function buildstring(str){
  return str
    .split('')
    .filter((character) => !'0123456789'.includes(character))
    .join('');
}

console.log(buildstring('How52363262362366are9you?'));
```

If you use `split(' ')` (or even break on `\s` to consider tabs and newlines), you'll have „words” (with interpunction).

By breaking up the code into smaller functions, you can compose them.
For example, the `.filter()` could be a `stripnumerals` function.

This way, you can compose the transformations as you please.

Comment: This produces the same result that the OP already had.

Comment: I'm aware of this. He asked for best practices on how to approach a problem like this.

Comment: But the OP also wrote that he wanted the words to be separated. Their call for "best practices" was misleading, since they didn't have a solution for that.